# Lambda: convert given number with base to decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

In math, to convert a number `n` of base 5 to base 10 is 14. I know how to get 14 with the following working

```
24base5 = 2*5^1 + 4*5^0
        = 14
```

I would like to implement this using lambda in a one-liner. However, I am not sure on how to decrement the power. The current coding that is not working is as follows:

```
n = 24
x = 5
print map(lambda n : n * x ** 1, n)
```

I do know how I can make the `x**1` to be decreasing with the loop.

**EDIT: I would like to know how it can be done so for converting to base 16 too**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `int` to parse numbers from base 10 to another base:

```
>>> int('24', 5)
14

# or as a lambda function:
>>> c = lambda n, b: int(str(n), b)
>>> c(24, 5)
14

# convert to hex
>>> hex(c(24,5))[2:]
'e'
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann, You're quite right. However we can use it both ways, because there's `str(n)`. But for the purpose of this task version with pure int argument is better. Thank you.

Comment: May i also know how to change your answer for converting to hex too without using hex()

Comment: @Kode.Error404, do you want to avoid using `hex()` at all? Why? With it you can nest them:  `hex(c(24,5))`.

Comment: I am trying to convert 24 base 5 to base 16 hence i was trying to make it to base 10 then to 16. hex did not seem to work. I asked how because I wanted to learn how if i were to convert to base 10

Comment: But now i have found it with this `print hex(int(str(n),x))[2:]`

Comment: @Kode.Error404, ok. Yes, you may chain them and throw away unnecessary line head '0x'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement it yourself instead of using `int` then you can use the `sum` function and a `for` loop inside the `lambda` (do note that the `for` loop traverses the string representation of `num` from end to start):

```
f = lambda num, base: sum(int(digit) * base ** index
                          for index, digit in enumerate(str(num)[::-1]))

print(f(24, 5))
# 14
```

Comment: May i know why this `print lambda num, base: sum(int(digit) * base ** index
                          for index, digit in enumerate(str(num)[::-1]))` prints an address?

Comment: @Kode.Error404 becuase you're printing the memory address of the function, not a result of a call to it.

Comment: is there a way to print directly without calling it the way you did?

Comment: You can surround the entire `lambda` definition with parenthesis then call it: `print (lambda num, base: sum(int(digit) * base ** index
                          for index, digit in enumerate(str(num)[::-1])))(24, 5)`